# SFML - How do I create an OpenGL context before showing the window?

Tags: opengl, windows, sfml, assets

I want to create an OpenGL context to initialize some assets before actually showing the window with SFML. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried `Window::setVisible(false)`?

Comment: Normally (with glfw for instance) you would make the window hidden by default and then grab the opengl context before showing the window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sf::Context context;
```

creates a valid OpenGL context.

You can find more info in the [official tutorial](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.2/window-opengl.php#opengl-without-a-window) or the [documentation](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.2/classsf_1_1Context.php).